# Do all harddrive docks have a limit of 2 TB?

Tags: hard-drive

I want to purchase a harddrive dock from [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&IsNodeId=1&Description=harddrive%20dock&bop=And&Order=REVIEWS&PageSize=20). Many of the docks say it handles a maximum of 2 TB. Others do not list their limit. Do all docks have a limit of 2 TB because of some fundamental limit of operating systems? I seem to recall something about Windows XP not being able to handle large harddrives. Could it be related to this issue? I'm using Windows Vista though.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all likelihood, it's a limitation of the SATA controller that the dock contains inside itself. It is most certainly not a limitation of Windows. If you can find out what controller the dock contains, you should be able to look up its drive limits.

Comment: What SATA controllers allow greater than 2 TB? I'm looking to purchase some 3 TB drives soon and don't want this dock to fail on me.

Comment: @JoJo Personally, I use the [NewerTech Voyager](http://www.newertech.com/products/voyager_index.php). This uses the Oxford 944SE chipset which supports as large of a drive as you can dock in it. (Not that I'm providing a shopping recommendation, as it's clearly against the rules in the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)).

Comment: Hmmm.. $50. The ones with 2 TB limit on Newegg are only $21... Choices, choices. I just know the more greedy I get, the more harddrive space I'll need. VHS -> DVD -> Bluray -> what's next? Videos are getting bigger and bigger each decade.

Comment: @JoJo Grab an HDD rack and build your own NAS! I took an old beige box, put FreeBSD on it and I've got the power of ZFS at my disposal. Hot-swappable, expandable, contractable, manipulatable storage at my fingertips. No running out of space in my future!

Answer (score 0):

Most older docks only support 2TB disks.

The ones that go beyond this limit will report a 'max supported disk size' of 3TB or higher in their specs.

Example: [this one](http://www.sharkoon.com/?q=en/node/1269) is a 'version 2' and supports 3TB disks, while [this](http://www.sharkoon.com/?q=en/content/sata-quickport-duo-v2) ('v1') does not.